# two same rows but one column with distinct value, how to combine them and get rid of another line

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BxKr.jpg)I have two rows exactly same value except one column, I want to combine them and add another value into new column

```
Name       Address        City    State    ID        ID Type
XYZ        123 address     New York  NY     123      Code1
XYZ       123 address      New York   NY    D561      Code2
ABC        895 address     Richmond    VA    568A      Code1
XAB        456 address     Dallas      TX    568       Code2
XAB        456 address      Dallas     TX    458A562    Code1
XYZ       123 address         New York  NY   123T        Code3
```

Result

```
Name       Address      City   State    Code1   Code2  code3
XYZ        123 Address   New York  NY   123      D561  123T
ABC        895 address    Richmond  VA  568A
XAB        456 address    Dallas    TX  458A562   563
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWHzw.jpg)

Comment: Will there be a max of two rows for each case, or can there be more?  Take a look at a PIVOT query.  Please tag questions with the proper database, and what you have tried.  Thanks

Comment: which dbms you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select Name, Addresss, City, State,
       min(id) as id1,
       (case when min(id) <> max(id) then max(id) end) as id2 
from t
group by Name, Addresss, City, State ;
```

Comment: I added new screenshot and I am using sql server

Comment: @Mike . . . I'm not sure what your point is.  This answer seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @ Gordon what happen if I have one more value Code 3 or Id3 value?

Comment: It is working as expected based on my example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give you the correct desired o/p as per above input sample or else for a standard you can use `PIVOT` keyword to have a new column

```
SELECT  Name, Address,City, State,   
        min(ID) AS ID1,max(ID) AS ID2 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Name, Address,City, State
```